# Agile Project Management with iOS, Android, and Server Components

Tags: agile, software-development

We are currently trying to start a project with three different OS's, iOS, Android, and Server components.  The argument has been on how should we create the stories, should there be a story for each OS and point each story, or should we create one story for all three OS's and point that one story.  Note: It's the same feature across the three different OS's, and there are different devs working on each OS.

Comment: Are you planning to have a common increase of functionality or is it OK if the app on one OS will be more developed than on another?

Answer (score 2):

You should write the **same user stories and acceptance tests for all the three Operating Systems**. By the way, since you have three platforms and three different groups of developers working on each of them, you will have **different effort estimations (story points) for the same story for each OS**. For this reason, I suggest you to keep track of the progress using **three different task boards**.